# Convert mesh to 3d segmentation Image

Tags: matlab, mesh, dicom, itk, meshlab

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to convert a 3D mesh to a segmented imagen in a format like dicom for example.
 The problem is that I have a 3D label volume in Dicom format. I create a mesh from it, and then process the mesh; so at the end I end up with a different mesh volume. Now I want to see how it looks in a per slice volume (Dicom).
I hope it is clear.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use ITK already, pair it with VTK. `vtkPolyDataToImageStencil` is what you are looking for.

http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/6.3/html/classvtkPolyDataToImageStencil.html

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this contribution](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27390-mesh-voxelisation) from MATLAB file exchange, seems to do exactly what you want and gives you a 3D array of logical values. Then you just need to save the volume as a DICOM file.